# How to pivot the table records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

How to group records and pivot them?
Sql query to retrieve the below records is as below:

```
select d.Name as DrawerBox
     , dt.Name as DrawerBoxType
     , di.Inches as Inches
     , isnull(dbc.Value, dc.Value) Value      
from DrawerBox_C dc
join DrawerBox d
  on d.DrawerBoxId = dc.DrawerBoxId
join DrawerBoxInches  di
  on di.DrawerBoxInchesId = dc.DrawerBoxInchesId
join DrawerBoxType dt
  on dt.DrawerBoxTypeId = dc.DrawerBoxTypeId
left join dbo.DrawerBox_Bid_C dbc
  on dbc.DrawerBox_C_Id = dc.DrawerBox_C_Id
  and dbc.BidId = 1
```

[image]

want output as this below format

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: How many inches options do you have?

Comment: There are 5 inches.12",18",24",30",36"

Comment: Do a GROUP BY, use case expressions for each inch option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a shot like this ... query ain't tested, if it fails let me know so i can fix it ... but that's what you want, you just need pivot

```
    select * from (
select d.Name as DrawerBox
 , dt.Name as DrawerBoxType
 , di.Inches as Inches
 , isnull(dbc.Value, dc.Value) Value      
from DrawerBox_C dc
    join DrawerBox d
        on d.DrawerBoxId = dc.DrawerBoxId
    join DrawerBoxInches  di
        on di.DrawerBoxInchesId = dc.DrawerBoxInchesId
    join DrawerBoxType dt
        on dt.DrawerBoxTypeId = dc.DrawerBoxTypeId
    left join dbo.DrawerBox_Bid_C dbc
        on dbc.DrawerBox_C_Id = dc.DrawerBox_C_Id
        and dbc.BidId = 1
) src
  PIVOT
  (
    Max(value) 
    for Inches in ([12], [18], [24], [30], [36])
  ) piv
order by DrawerBox, DrawerBoxType
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following to run your query dynamically. This means that even if you add new "Inches" values it will automatically create them for you. Also provided is a manual insert below so that you can test. Also note that this is grabbing the max "Value" for each DrawerBox/DrawerBoxType. You can also use "Avg", "Min", "Sum" instead if you prefer.

```
Drop Table #PivotRecs
Create Table #PivotRecs (DrawerBox nvarchar(200), DrawerBoxType nvarchar(200), Inches int, Value int)
Insert Into #PivotRecs
select d.Name as DrawerBox
     , dt.Name as DrawerBoxType
     , di.Inches as Inches
     , isnull(dbc.Value, dc.Value) Value      
from DrawerBox_C dc
join DrawerBox d
  on d.DrawerBoxId = dc.DrawerBoxId
join DrawerBoxInches  di
  on di.DrawerBoxInchesId = dc.DrawerBoxInchesId
join DrawerBoxType dt
  on dt.DrawerBoxTypeId = dc.DrawerBoxTypeId
left join dbo.DrawerBox_Bid_C dbc
  on dbc.DrawerBox_C_Id = dc.DrawerBox_C_Id
  and dbc.BidId = 1


  --Insert Into #PivotRecs
  --Select 'Melamine', 'Standard', 12, 3 Union
  --Select 'Melamine', 'Standard', 18, 6 Union
  --Select 'Melamine', 'Standard', 24, 9 Union
  --Select 'Melamine', 'Standard', 30, 12 Union
  --Select 'Melamine', 'Standard', 36, 15 Union
  --Select 'Melamine', 'File', 12, 5 Union
  --Select 'Melamine', 'File', 18, 8 Union
  --Select 'Melamine', 'File', 24, 11 Union
  --Select 'Melamine', 'File', 30, 14 Union
  --Select 'Melamine', 'File', 36, 17 


Declare @Inch int, @SQL nvarchar(max),@Inchs nvarchar(max),@SQL2 nvarchar(max), @i int
Set @i = 0
Set @SQL = ''
Set @SQL2 = ''
Set @Inchs = ''
DECLARE iCursor CURSOR
LOCAL
FAST_FORWARD
FOR 
Select Distinct Inches From #PivotRecs  Order By Inches
  OPEN iCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM iCursor INTO @Inch
WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
BEGIN
If(@i=1)
Begin
Set @SQL = @SQL + ',['+Cast(@Inch as nvarchar(4))+']'
Set @Inchs= @Inchs + ','+Cast(@Inch as nvarchar(4))+''
End
If(@i=0)
Begin
Set @SQL = @SQL + '['+Cast(@Inch as nvarchar(4))+']'
Set @Inchs = @Inchs + ''+Cast(@Inch as nvarchar(4))+''
Set @i = 1
End

FETCH NEXT FROM iCursor INTO @Inch
Continue
End 
Set @SQL2 = 
'Select * 
From
(Select Distinct DrawerBox, DrawerBoxType, Inches, Value From #PivotRecs) a
pivot (
   max (a.Value) 
   for Inches in ('+@SQL+'))   
   as Inches
   Order By 1'

Exec SP_ExecuteSQL @SQL2
```